# Set selectedItem in WPF TreeView with DataContext bound to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview, linq-to-xml

I have TreeView in my WPF window. The TreeViews DataContext is bound to a XDocument.

I am in search for setting the selectedItem from code behind. As the nodes returned by for example .ItemContainerGenerator.Items are of type System.Xml.Linq.XElement and not System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem I can not just set isSelected :-(

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

**EDIT**:
XAML Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AttributeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
        Margin="3,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
         Foreground="{StaticResource xmAttributeBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
            <TextBlock Text="=&quot;"
         Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Foreground="{StaticResource xmlValueBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
            <TextBlock Text="&quot;"
         Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="False">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="Root" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
            <ItemsControl
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AttributeTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AttrConverter}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="Elements" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FirstNode.FirstNode.NodeType}" Value="Text" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiString2StringKonverter}">
                            <Binding Path="FirstNode.Value" />
                            <Binding Path="FirstNode.NextNode.Value" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FirstNode.NodeType}" Value="Text">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} = {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="FirstNode.Value"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="LizenzAnsicht"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Elements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NodeTemplate}"
      />
```

Code Behind:
...

```
LizenzAnsicht.DataContext = XDocument.Load(<Path to XML-File>);
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning the items and not the treenode : ItemContainerGenerator.Items.  Why not return ItemContainerGenerator

Comment: improve your question with your Code. That would be awesome!

Comment: @jdweng: I think ItemContainerGenerator will not give me an Object with the needed properties or Methods. I think I need to iterate through all Items of the TreeView until I find the right one ... this one is needed as an object with isEnabled Property ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping a weekend about this I found an answer myself. There were some more problems as only the return type.

The solution is, to get the matching ItemContainer for the Item. This Container is of type TreeViewItem, where I can set isSelected an the like.

As an example is most of the time better for understanding, I give one. The following function will search for a XML- node in a TreeView- object and return a TreeViewItem, that contains the matching Node. If no Match is found null is returned.
The matching node is expanded.
The XML is handled in a System.Xml.linq.XDocument which is bound to the System.Windows.Controls.TreeView DataContext.
When calling the function The TreeView is set as ic.

```
public static TreeViewItem SearchNodeInTreeView(ItemsControl ic, XElement NodeDescription, string indent = "")
{
    TreeViewItem ret = null;
    foreach (object o in ic.Items)
    {
        if (o is XElement)
        {
            var x = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o);
            if (XNode.DeepEquals((o as XElement), NodeDescription))
            {
                ret = x as TreeViewItem;
            }
            else if ((o as XElement).HasElements){
                if (x != null)
                {
                    bool expanded = (x as TreeViewItem).IsExpanded;
                    (x as TreeViewItem).IsExpanded = true;
                    (x as TreeViewItem).UpdateLayout();
                    ret = SearchNodeInTreeView (x as TreeViewItem, NodeDescription, indent + "  ");
                    if (ret == null)
                    {
                        (x as TreeViewItem).IsExpanded = expanded;
                        (x as TreeViewItem).UpdateLayout();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (ret != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I hope I can help anybody with this.